# Wrong dependency: Dependency from whole array when only one value is being used

Tags: frama-c

I'm working with frama-c to make a dependency analysis of our code base and we have run into a situation that I have summarized in the following example.

We have a our entry point "runnable" for the analysis:

```
typedef unsigned char uint8;
typedef unsigned short uint16;

void ReadFunction(uint16 *const data);

extern uint16 test_return;

void runnable(void){

    uint16 test_array[8];
    
    ReadFunction(test_array);
    test_return = test_array[4];

}
```

In our example we are using a local variable **test_array[8]** to read a value given by our **ReadFunction** and then taking only one value from that array (**test_array[4]**) and assigning it to the external value **test_return**.

Inside of ReadFunction the code is as follows:

```
typedef unsigned short uint16;

typedef uint16 custom_arr_type[8];

extern custom_arr_type test_interface;

extern void mem_copy(void * dst, const void * src, uint16 length);

void ReadFunction(uint16 *const data)
{
   mem_copy(data, test_interface, sizeof(custom_arr_type));
}
```

where mem_copy is:

```
void mem_copy(void * dst,
           const void * src,
           uint16 length)
{
   uint8 *          d = (uint8 *)dst;
   const uint8 *    s = (const uint8 *)src;  
   uint16 i;
   for (i = 0; i < (length); i++)
     {
       d[i] = s[i];
     }
}
```

When analyzing the entrypoint **runnable** with the following command: *frama-c -eva -deps -inout -lib-entry -no-annot -eva-initialized-locals -eva-auto-loop-unroll 10 -c11 example.i read_example.i lib_example.i -main runnable* we produce the following output:

```
[kernel] Parsing example.i (no preprocessing)
[kernel] Parsing read_example.i (no preprocessing)
[kernel] Parsing lib_example.i (no preprocessing)
[eva] Analyzing an incomplete application starting at runnable
[eva] Computing initial state
[eva] Initial state computed
[eva:initial-state] Values of globals at initialization
  test_return ∈ [--..--]
  test_interface[0..7] ∈ [--..--]
[eva] lib_example.i:21: starting to merge loop iterations
[eva] done for function runnable
[eva] ====== VALUES COMPUTED ======
[eva:final-states] Values at end of function mem_copy:
  test_array[0..7] ∈ [--..--]
  d ∈ {{ (uint8 *)&test_array }}
  s ∈ {{ (uint8 const *)&test_interface }}
  i ∈ [16..32767]
[eva:final-states] Values at end of function ReadFunction:
  test_array[0..7] ∈ [--..--]
[eva:final-states] Values at end of function runnable:
  test_return ∈ [--..--]
  test_array[0..7] ∈ [--..--]
[eva:summary] ====== ANALYSIS SUMMARY ======
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  3 functions analyzed (out of 3): 100% coverage.
  In these functions, 15 statements reached (out of 15): 100% coverage.
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  No errors or warnings raised during the analysis.
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  0 alarms generated by the analysis.
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  No logical properties have been reached by the analysis.
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[from] Computing for function mem_copy
[from] Done for function mem_copy
[from] Computing for function ReadFunction
[from] Done for function ReadFunction
[from] Computing for function runnable
[from] Done for function runnable
[from] ====== DEPENDENCIES COMPUTED ======
  These dependencies hold at termination for the executions that terminate:
[from] Function mem_copy:
  test_array[0..7] FROM test_interface[0..7]; dst; src; length (and SELF)
[from] Function ReadFunction:
  test_array[0..7] FROM test_interface[0..7]; data (and SELF)
[from] Function runnable:
  test_return FROM test_interface[0..7]
[from] ====== END OF DEPENDENCIES ======
[inout] InOut (internal) for function mem_copy:
  Operational inputs:
    test_interface[0..7]; dst; src; length
  Operational inputs on termination:
    test_interface[0..7]; dst; src; length
  Sure outputs:
    d; s; i
[inout] InOut (internal) for function ReadFunction:
  Operational inputs:
    test_interface[0..7]; data
  Operational inputs on termination:
    test_interface[0..7]; data
  Sure outputs:
    \nothing
[inout] InOut (internal) for function runnable:
  Operational inputs:
    test_array[4]; test_interface[0..7]
  Operational inputs on termination:
    test_array[4]; test_interface[0..7]
  Sure outputs:
    test_return
```

Now, the expected result here four our main function would be to have a dependency from **test_return** to **test_interface[4]** since it is my understanding that local variables like **test_array** will never appear in the dependency analysis. However, instead of having a dependency from one value of our array to our return value, we get a dependency from the whole array (**test_interface[0..7]**) to the return value.

I have tried simplifying even more this example, to rule out any possibility of the custom data types or the function calls to be causing this behavior:

```
int test_return;
int test_extern_array[8];

void runnable(void){

    int test_array[8];
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        test_array[i] = test_extern_array[i];
    }
    test_return = test_array[4];
    
}
```

Which produces the following output:

```
[kernel] Parsing example.i (no preprocessing)
[eva] Analyzing an incomplete application starting at runnable
[eva] Computing initial state
[eva] Initial state computed
[eva:initial-state] Values of globals at initialization
  test_return ∈ [--..--]
  test_extern_array[0..7] ∈ [--..--]
[eva:loop-unroll] example.i:8: Automatic loop unrolling.
[eva] done for function runnable
[eva] ====== VALUES COMPUTED ======
[eva:final-states] Values at end of function runnable:
  test_return ∈ [--..--]
  test_array[0..7] ∈ [--..--]
[eva:summary] ====== ANALYSIS SUMMARY ======
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 function analyzed (out of 1): 100% coverage.
  In this function, 10 statements reached (out of 10): 100% coverage.
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  No errors or warnings raised during the analysis.
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  0 alarms generated by the analysis.
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  No logical properties have been reached by the analysis.
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[from] Computing for function runnable
[from] Done for function runnable
[from] ====== DEPENDENCIES COMPUTED ======
  These dependencies hold at termination for the executions that terminate:
[from] Function runnable:
  test_return FROM test_extern_array[0..7]
[from] ====== END OF DEPENDENCIES ======
[inout] InOut (internal) for function runnable:
  Operational inputs:
    test_extern_array[0..7]; test_array[4]
  Operational inputs on termination:
    test_extern_array[0..7]; test_array[4]
  Sure outputs:
    test_return; i
```

And still in this case we obtain a dependency to our return value from the whole array instead of the specific position that has been used.

I have tried reading through all the frama-c manual and the eva plugin manual to find any cases similar to mine or any analysis option that could help get a more accurate dependency. I tried using the *-eva-precision* option but the results are the same.

Is frama-c correct here and I'm misinterpreting the results?
Is there any way to get a more precise dependency for this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes (and no), and not currently.

Frama-C/Eva is *correct*, as in, *sound* (it does not "forget" to consider any possible value), but when the From plug-in is used, its result is less precise than what Eva computes itself. In particular, options such as `-eva-auto-loop-unroll` allow splitting different analysis contexts *inside* Eva (thus keeping maximum precision), but when the analysis terminates, results are consolidated by program point, per call stack, but not per loop iteration. That is, the different iterations inside a loop end up merged before From can get the information it needs from Eva, which explains why it shows the imprecise result. So, currently, it is not possible to get a more precise result.

Note that the analysis computed by From could nowadays be written as an Eva abstract domain, which would allow it to be more precise, since it would run "at the same time as" Eva itself. But that will require considerable time and effort.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm not really sure what you mean by "From could nowadays be written as an Eva abstract domain". Could you please provide any more information about this, or where to find this on the documentation? Even if it requires considerable time and effort, if this solution could help us solve this issue and get more precision on the dependencies for the array I would consider implementing it. I have looked into the abstract domain on the EVA documentation but I don't see how it can be related to the from section. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Previously, there was a plug-in called Value Analysis. From, InOut and other plug-ins were developed separately but dependent on it. Nowadays, Eva (Evolved value analysis) offers ways to compute such data in a way that does not require a separate plugin, but just another abstract domain (like Gauges, Symbolic equalities, Octagons, etc). But this requires some *serious* rewriting, which the Eva authors themselves consider complex. For instance, it requires knowledge about several of Eva's internal data structures, which are still undocumented and constantly evolving.